# Finding complex roots of polynomial by proving trigonometric identity

Tags: polynomials

> Consider the polynomial equation $5z^4-11z^3+16z^2-11z+5=0$, which has four complex roots with modulus one.
>
> Let $z=\operatorname{cis}\theta$.
>
> (a) Show that $5\cos2\theta-11\cos\theta+8=0$
>
> (b) Hence determine the four roots of the equation in the form $a+ib$, where $a$ and $b$ are real.

How do you get the identity in the first part, without leaving any $\cos(4\theta)$ and $\cos(3\theta)$ terms?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: sorry i edited it now

Comment: Have you tried simplifying $\cos(4 \theta)$ and $\cos(3 \theta)$? You can simplify the first using the double-angle identity, and the second using the angle addition identity.

Comment: The polynomial's coefficients are symmetric. Then you can divide the equation by $z^2$ and re-write it as a polynomial in $z+\frac{1}{z}$. This will result in a degree $2$ polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

a)

$z = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta\\
\bar z = \cos\theta - i\sin \theta\\
2\cos\theta = z - \bar z$

$\frac{1}{z} = \frac {\bar z}{|z|}$

since $|z| = 1, \bar z = z^{-1}$

$\cos \theta = \frac 12 (z + z^{-1})\\
\cos 2\theta =\frac 12 (z^2+z^{-2})$

$5\cos 2\theta - 11\cos \theta+8 = \frac{5}{2}z^2 - \frac{11}{2} z + 8 - \frac {11}{2}z^{-1} +  \frac{5}{2} z^{-2} = \frac {1}{2z^2}(5z^4 - 11z^3 + 16z^2 - 11z + 5) = 0$

b)

$\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2 \theta - 1$

$10\cos^2\theta - 11\cos \theta + 3 = 0\\
(5\cos\theta - 3)(2\cos\theta - 1)$

$\cos\theta = \frac 12, \frac 35\\
z  = \frac 12 \pm \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i\\
z = \frac 35 \pm \frac 45i$